# Is there a SE site to ask "what is this song"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm wondering if there is an appropriate StackExchange site that I can ask "What is the song playing in the tv series season x episode y, minute z"?

Comment: Possibly the [movies.se], but do be sure to read their [on topic guidelines](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to be safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging by [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/19140/13707), it would be off-topic on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/). If it is a science-fiction or fantasy series, however, it seems be on-topic on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com), going by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/46302/20840).

Either way, the [Music Fans](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans?referrer=_UzUVNm3qItlGleSE5XxcQ2) proposal seems to intend to accept such questions, at least judging by [this example question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans/65736#65736).

Answer (score 3):

There isn't **yet**.

We looked at it on [Music](https://music.stackexchange.com/), but it wouldn't fit there...however [Music Fans](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans) is in Commitment now! Please sign up and get your friends to sign up as well.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps check out [Movies & TV.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/). However, as Oded said, be sure to read their [on topic guidelines](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

If you think you can wait a while, you can ask it on the [Music Fans](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans) proposal, if it gets into beta.